# Must a subspace contain all the elements in the field of the parent vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

We often refer to a vector space as $V$ when it's clear what the field and the operations are, but in reality a vector space is a composite object $(V, \mathbb{F}, +, \cdot)$. My question is, when we talk about a subspace being a subset $W$ (or more rigorously, $(W, \mathbb{F}, +, \cdot)$) of $V$, do we just mean that the set of vector objects of $W$ is a subset of the set of vector objects of $V$, while the the fields contained in $W$ and $V$ are the same, or can the fields be different?

Answer (score 2):

The field is the same. Specifically, if $(V, \mathbb{F}, +, \cdot)$ is a vector space, then a subspace of it is a tuple $(W, \mathbb{F}, +, \cdot)$ where $W \subseteq V$, the operations $+$ and $\cdot$ are the restrictions of the original operations, and $(W, \mathbb{F}, +, \cdot)$ itself satisfies the vector space axioms.

Answer (score 0):

> Must a subspace contain all the elements in the field of the parent vector space (?)

It's unclear what's being asked here. Do you mean "If $(W, \mathbb{F}) \hookrightarrow (V, \mathbb{F})$, then $\mathbb{F} \subseteq W$"? The answer is no, for it's not even the case generally that $\mathbb{F} \subseteq V$

> My question is, when we talk about a subspace being a subset $W$
> (or more rigorously, $(W,\mathbb{F},+,⋅)$
> ) of $V$
> , do we just mean that the set of vector objects of $W$
> is a subset of the set of vector objects of $V$ $-$

I think you meant "a subset being a subspace", and no, that's not all that's meant: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4831674/help-understanding-why-this-set-is-not-a-vector-space-when-it-seemingly-passes-b/4831709#4831709) about the operations having to agree on a certain sense (of being restrictions)

> [...] while the the fields contained in $W$ and $V$ are the same $-$

Again, it's not in principle the case that $\mathbb{F} \subseteq W, V$

> or can the fields be different?

Now this is interesting: in principle on can conceive of a notion of structure, a pair consisting of a field and a vector space over it, such that a morphism would be a 'compatible' pair of morphisms, as in

$(\mathbb{F}, W) \rightarrow (\mathbb{E}, V)$ with $\mathbb{F} \subseteq \mathbb{E}$ and $W \rightarrow_\mathbb{F} V$

that is, the 'second coordinate morphism' would be an ordinary $\mathbb{F}$-linear map